# If $\lim x_{n} = 0$, then $\frac{1}{|x_{n}|}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

If $x_{n}$ is a sequence such that $\lim x_{n} = 0$, then $\frac{1}{|x_{n}|} = \infty$. Is this true?

What about if we have another sequence $y_{n}$ such that $\lim y_{n} = 0$, then either $\lim \frac{1}{y_{n}} = +\infty$ or $\lim \frac{1}{y_{n}} = -\infty$

Is there a way to prove/disprove some of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First statement is only true if there exists some N such that $x_n \ne 0$ for $n \ge N$. Otherwise $\frac{1}{|x_n|}$ is undefined for some n and the limit does not exist.

Second statement is not true.
Here's a counterexample:

$y_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$

whose limit is 0 as $n \to \infty$

$z_n = \frac{1}{y_n} = (-1)^nn$

whose limit as $n \to \infty$ is not $\infty$ or $-\infty$

Answer (score 3):

Let $ (x_n)$ be a real sequence such that for $ n $ great enough $ x_n\ne 0 $ and $\lim_{n\to+\infty}x_n=0$

then

$$(\forall A>0) (\exists N\in\Bbb N)\;\;:\;$$
$$n\ge N \;\implies \; 0<|x_n|<\frac 1A$$

thus

$$n\ge N \;\implies \;\; \frac{1}{|x_n|}>A$$

which proves that
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{1}{|x_n|}=+\infty$$

For the second, take $$y_n=\frac{-1}{n+1}$$
then
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{1}{y_n}=-\infty$$

Comment: Beat me to it. Nice work

Comment: Same :( but $x_n\neq 0$ for all $n$ right?

Comment: @RyanK Not necessarily. When you deal with limits, enough great indices are sufficient.

Comment: @RyanK if $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$, then $x_n$ will eventually be strictly nonzero. I don't have an intuitive reason for why this is the case, but there are some out there.

Comment: $1/|x_n|$ (is its own sequence) is not well defined. I would think

Comment: @A.E.Rosas, if $x_n=0$ for all $n$, then $x_n\to 0$

Comment: @RyanK I said that $ x_n\ne 0$ for great $ n$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah, Yes, I see, however the question asks about the sequence $1/|x_n|$, which is not defined if $x_n=0$ for any $n$, right?

Comment: @RyanK I made a mistake in my explanation. I should have said "if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{x_n}$ exists, then $x_n$ is eventually strictly nonzero". Sorry about that!

Comment: @A.E.Rosas, hmm, I would think that if the sequence $1/x_n$ is defined at all, $x_n=0$ for all $n$. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Oops, cannot edit the comment, but meant to say  "I would think that if the sequence $1/x_n$ is defined at all, $x_n\neq 0$ for all $n$."

Answer (score 0):

It all boils down to

$$0<|x_n|<\epsilon\iff \dfrac1{|x_n|}>M=\frac1\epsilon.$$

But neither

$$0<|y_n|<\epsilon\iff \dfrac1{y_n}>M=\frac1\epsilon$$

nor

$$0<|y_n|<\epsilon\iff \dfrac1{y_n}<-M=-\frac1\epsilon$$

do hold.